# Reading database data from more than two tables into a Swing table but the frame hangs indefinitely

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, resultset

Am trying to read database data into a Swing table from two database tables but the frame hands indefinitely.

```
 JDBCConnectionPigs c11 = new JDBCConnectionPigs();

  try {
   c11.createConnection().setAutoCommit(false);
   PreparedStatement ps = c11.createConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM sow_info");
   ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
   int i1=0, a =0,b=1, c1=2,  d1 =3, e= 4,fs=5;      
   while(rs.next()){
   data4 =new ArrayList<>();
   data4.add(a, rs.getString("sow_info_id"));
   data4.add(b, rs.getString("sow_name"));
    data4.add(c1,rs.getString("sow_colour"));
    data4.add(d1,rs.getString("sow_breed"));
    data4.add(e,rs.getString("sow_date_of_birth"));

   PreparedStatement ps1 = c11.createConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT staff_id FROM staff");
    ResultSet rst=ps1.executeQuery();
    while(rst.last() ){
 stafid= rst.getString("staff_id");
    }
  data4.add(e, stafid);
   data5.add(i1, data4); 
  }
   model = new MyTableModel(data5, column1);
  jTable2.setModel(model);
  c11.createConnection().setAutoCommit(true);
  } catch (SQLException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger( SowSow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
    if(c11!=null){
   c11.closeConnection();
   }
```

I need help to know the cause and how I can implement it differently.

Comment: Why you use while(rst.last() ){ in your second query?

Comment: @YeWin, i used while(rst.last() ){ in my second query to put the cursor to the last row because i need the staff id of a staff who has just logged in the system

Comment: can you use sorting to get the recently logged user.

Comment: @Elango: if the recent user id is less than other user's ids in the table, does it return the recent or the largest or smallest depending on the sort criteria?

Comment: @Googo please try this code 'PreparedStatement ps1 = c11.createConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT staff_id FROM staff");
ResultSet rst=ps1.executeQuery();
rst.last()
{
 stafid= rst.getString("staff_id");
}while(rst.previous());'

Comment: which data base you are using. Refer to the below link.
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_last.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code.I hope this working.

```
PreparedStatement ps1 = c11.createConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT staff_id FROM staff");
ResultSet rst=ps1.executeQuery();
rst.last()
{
 stafid= rst.getString("staff_id");
}while(rst.previous());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want only the last staff_id, why do you want to get all the staff_id from the table and iterate over it. Get the latest staff id using a query like below.

```sql
SELECT staff_id FROM staff ORDER BY staff_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I need to understand whether the database returns the last row or the row with the biggest figure. otherwise it's working but i don't know how

Comment: the row with highest staff_id will be returned.

Comment: this doesn't serve my end because i want to return the id of the staff currently logged in whose id may not necessarily be larger or smaller than the ids in the table.

Comment: are you inserting the currently logged staff id in to the table staff.

Comment: That's right. As soon as the staff member logs in, the id is stored in the table which maintains all the past login ids